# store high decimal values in python Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

value1 and value 2 is an array, has values close to each other
This would result temp to have very high decimal values

```
temp = tf.sub(value1,value2)
```

However, when I tried to print temp out, it contains array with 0.0 values due to high decimal values in the array.

How do I maintain the precision of all the variables?

Comment: Take a look at the [`Decimal` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by setting the type of `value1` and `value2` before applying `tf.sub`. For example:

```
value1=tf.constant(5.0000000001,dtype=tf.float64)
value2=tf.constant(5.0000000002,dtype=tf.float64)
s=tf.sub(value1,value2)
sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
s.eval()
```

This prints `-1.000000082740371e-10`

Same for arrays:

```
value1=tf.constant([5.0000000001,2.0001],dtype=tf.float64)
value2=tf.constant([5.0000000002,2.000],dtype=tf.float64)
s=tf.sub(value1,value2)
sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
s.eval()
```

This prints `array([ -1.00000008e-10,   1.00000000e-04])`

​